# jmeter HTTP Request get Path from XML element

Tags: xml, web-services, jmeter, performance-testing

I try to read `XML elements` in order to change the path of the `HTTP Request` of the performance test. 
My sample `XML` data

```
<test>
   <paths>
       <path>/?test=test1</path>
       <path>/?test=test2</path>
   </paths>
</test>
```

Here is the path that I tried to read it through `BeanShell` Sampler

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for parsing XML data.

Demo:

[image: JMeterXpath]

Example queries:

- `//path` - match both elements, you can use the output variables with [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to hit all endpoints
- `//path[1]` - matches only `/?test=test1`
- `//path[2]` - matches only `/?test=test2`

See [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) for more information on XPath syntax

Comment: thank you for your help, another question is how can I add my XML file in order to XPath it through XPath extractor

Comment: You can add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, use `file` as protocol and specify your XML file location in `Path` section like `d:/data/file1.xml`. See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) article for more detailed description of the approach.